# Debugging seg fault (can't modify source code or makefile)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb, strace

I'm trying to debug a seg fault in C in a research code. I cannot modify the source code/makefile. Since I can't modify the makefile (i.e., recompile the program) and the executable was not compiled with the -g option, I assume that throws gdb debugging out the window? Or is there a way to use gdb without compiling the executable using -g?

I could request to make changes to the source code, but I am almost certain the seg fault is due to one of my input files, so it shouldn't be a source code problem.

Someone had suggested I use "strace," which I am not very familiar with. Here is the end of the output when I strace'd my program:

```
close(27)                               = 0
munmap(0x2abe4843d000, 65536)           = 0
write(2, "==== backtrace ====\n", 20==== backtrace ====
)   = 20
write(2, " 2 0x00000000000597bc mxm_handle"..., 113 2 0x00000000000597bc mxm_handle_error()  /var/tmp/OFED_topdir/BUILD/mxm-3.3.3055/src/mxm/util/debug/debug.c:641
) = 113
write(2, " 3 0x000000000005992c mxm_error_"..., 121 3 0x000000000005992c mxm_error_signal_handler()  /var/tmp/OFED_topdir/BUILD/mxm-3.3.3055/src/mxm/util/debug/debug.c:616
) = 121
write(2, " 4 0x00000037ccc326a0 killpg()  "..., 37 4 0x00000037ccc326a0 killpg()  ??:0
) = 37
write(2, " 5 0x00000000004ec6ef interpLema"..., 99 5 0x00000000004ec6ef interpLemansToMopar_linear()  /home/dzdang/w16/sources/mopar_bc_interp.c:559
) = 99
write(2, " 6 0x000000000040c4ee main()  /h"..., 68 6 0x000000000040c4ee main()  /home/dzdang/w16/sources/lemans.c:611
) = 68
write(2, " 7 0x00000037ccc1ed5d __libc_sta"..., 48 7 0x00000037ccc1ed5d __libc_start_main()  ??:0
) = 48
write(2, " 8 0x0000000000403c99 _start()  "..., 37 8 0x0000000000403c99 _start()  ??:0
) = 37
write(2, "===================\n", 20===================
)   = 20
brk(0x2958000)                          = 0x2958000
tgkill(15432, 15432, SIGSEGV)           = 0
rt_sigreturn(0x3c48)                    = 46993935941696
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Segmentation fault
```

Any ideas what this means? Or any suggestions on how to debug?

Comment: Erroneous input data should not generate a segfault.  That's it, really.  An error message, say 'Input data bad at lineXX', is fine.

Comment: How about putting commands to compile directly to your terminal without using makefile to get executable with debug information?

Comment: This code involves reading in input files and stores them in dynamic allocated arrays. I was thinking that perhaps the input file was erroneous and it led to incorrect reads (or no reads at all), and thus when trying to access that array, it may be out of bounds?    There isn't much error checking coded into this program.

Comment: @MikeCAT   hmmmm. Would this be practical for very MANY source codes? I have over 500+ files written in C&Fortran that are linked together.

Comment: Since you can't edit or recompile, there's no real debugging you can do it seems. The code contained a bug, end of. The most likely cause here is probably dereferencing a NULL pointer, or accessing -in any way- out of bounds memory

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yes. Fortunately, the program tells me which which line (+/-a few lines) the code crashes at. The line that I am pretty sure it is crashing at involves arithmetic involving a deferenced pointer (double *) and a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: Any code that generates a segfault is buggy.  C defines no mechanism for producing one, so a program can segfault only by exercising undefined behavior, and a program that may exercise undefined behavior is, perforce, buggy.

Comment: @user5965026: Have you checked the files that are mentioned in strace output (eg `mopar_bc_interp.c`)? Maybe they can provide you with a clue as to what happened

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, the code isn't definitely very well written. There aren't many error checks present. It relies the user to know how to correctly set up  and format the input files, which is dumb I know.

Comment: You can run a program under `gdb` even if you have neither internal nor external debug symbols.  If it segfaults, you can get the corresponding stack trace.  That might be of *some* use even without the debug symbols.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I am doing that at the moment. I'm trying to learn what the above output of strace actually means. I never used it before.

Comment: You could try running the program under `valgrind`.  Inasmuch as a segfault almost surely indicates some form of memory access error, `valgrind` may give you some additional information.

Comment: Overall, however, it sounds like you might spend your time more effectively by going over the input files very carefully to check their validity, or even by writing a program to validate them.

Comment: Also, if you have the sources to look at, how is it that you cannot recompile?  And if you don't have the sources to look at, how is it that you hope your debugging efforts will help you identify a problem with your input?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks. I do have some experience with valgrind, but I can't use it atm, because it is not installed on our clusters (currently, I do not have the ability to install programs or to move the files around).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Regarding your last comment. The files are located on a protected server. I only have read-only access to the source code (but I requested a copy of the code today so I should be getting it pretty soon). I was trying to see if there's anything I can do while waiting to obtain an editable copy of the code.

Comment: I don't get it.  If you have read access to the source, then you are physically able to make your own copy of it.  I don't see why or how you need anyone else's help to get an editable copy.

Answer (score 0):

"*...but I am almost certain the seg fault is due to one of my input files*"

Then your debugging should concentrate on your input files. Is there a specification of the input?

If you have many input files and checking the files manually would be unfeasible, you could write a validator in C that checks all the input files for the proper format and reports erors. With those validated files the program in question won't crash anymore (hopefully).

(EDIT)

As for the debugging of the inputs, try a minimal input and expand that untill you are at the complete input. Somewhere a crash will occur that may give you have an indication.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume that throws gdb debugging out the window?
>   I am almost certain the seg fault is due to one of my input files, so it shouldn't be a source code problem.

You are making a *lot* of unwarranted assumptions.

1. A `SIGSEGV` is *always* a source code problem: invalid input should produce an error, not a crash.
2. The output from `strace` that you show contains file and line info, which *usually* means that the program is in fact compiled with `-g`.
3. GDB is perfectly capable of debugging programs compiled without `-g`, but it requires a skilled operator.
4. The program appears to self-report an error of some kind. Unfortunately you've removed all the relevant parts of that error, and show only the stack trace (which doesn't mean anything without the earlier output).

What you *should* do:

1. Stop making unwarranted assumptions and guesses.
2. Edit your question (or start a new one), showing the error that the program actually reports.
3. Run the program under GDB, and observe that you can in fact see file / line info, and *likely* parameter and local variable values.
4. Read the source, understand how and why it may crash, examine variables at point of crash, understand the cause (i.e. actually debug the problem).